# asp.net-boilerplate host swagger login, how?

Tags: authentication, swagger, asp.net-boilerplate

I am new to swagger and I have done several projects with asp.netboilerplate and its an awesome framework.
However just a simple question. I did an authorise from the swagger ui for the event host sample app but the swagger ui says that I still need to login.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Swagger authentication helpers](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/pull/87#issuecomment-316750655) from the browser console:

> Example flow 1: User is logged into application
>
> - Run `abp.swagger.addCsrfToken()` in the console to authenticate
> - Refresh to unauthenticate
>
> Example flow 2: User is logged in via Postman
>
> - Run `abp.auth.setToken(authToken)` and `abp.swagger.addAuthToken()` in the console to authenticate
> - Refresh to unauthenticate
> - Subsequently, run `abp.swagger.addAuthToken()` in the console to authenticate
>
> Example flow 3: User is not logged in
>
> - Run `abp.swagger.login()` in the console to authenticate
> - Refresh to unauthenticate
> - Subsequently, run `abp.swagger.addAuthToken()` in the console to authenticate

Comment: Awesome as always guys. Works fine on IE and Chrome.

Comment: just wondering why I when I run get all users I only see this.{
  "result": {
    "totalCount": 2,
    "items": []
  },
  "targetUrl": null,
  "success": true,
  "error": null,
  "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
  "__abp": true
} I would expect to see the full object graph of the users coming back?

Comment: I could not reproduce that.